# Question about terminology for a music sheet

Tags: chords, terminology, lyrics, lead-sheets

I have developed an application for musicians that produces [this](http://live.chordastic.com/livesong) output and I am not sure if we are using the correct terminology.

We currently use `Chords and lyrics sheet` but I think this is not the most popular description.

I recently found the following alternatives:

- Chord charts [with lyrics]
- Music chord tabs
- Lead sheet
- Sheet music
- Lyrics and chords

What is the correct terminology for [this](http://live.chordastic.com/livesong) kind of music sheet?

Comment: A comment, thus not an answer - I find these difficult to read, as there is no indication of how long each chord lasts. If you know the song, it's fine. Could you include barlines?

Comment: Look at 'lead sheets'. They show what you need - words, chords, with dots and barlines.

Comment: Lead sheets have barlines but my application doesn't have these.

Comment: Lead sheets also have the basic melody and chord symbols, not just the chords.

Comment: @Tim : I have created bar lines using the pipe symbol |. It's not released yet but you can have a look at http://snag.gy/nuM9k.jpg and tell me what do you think

Comment: I think it'll make a BIG difference to readers. However, the barlines aren't all in the right places, and some are missing. Once that's sorted, it'll be good. It would be good to get feedback from others, pos. or neg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of your name suggestions aren't wrong.

- Chords and lyrics sheet -> This seems a bit long, but it is accurate, since it describes exactly what we are looking at
- Chord charts [with lyrics]-> Short and to the point.
- Music chord tabs -> Tabs seems wrong here, because you don't include a tablature in your app.
- Lead sheet -> Like Tim said, the app isn't a lead sheet either. Here is what a lead sheet looks like:

[image]

- Sheet music -> A bit generic; not wrong, but it doesn't really specify what we are going to look at.
- Lyrics and chords -> This is pretty correct too.

I think that *Lyrics and chords* and *Chord charts [with lyrics]* are the most fitting here. But maybe Lyrics and Chords seems more correct, because it looks like the app emphasizes on the lyrics.